# Activate Office 2010 running in PlayOnLinux with a KMS server

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, license

Is it possible to activate a volume licensed copy of Microsoft Office installed using PlayOnLinux with my organisation's Key Management server?

The installation with PlayOnLinux worked flawlessly but the not long afterwards the activation notification pops up with "Error 0x8007232B" in the bottom left corner http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929826 informing that the KMS services host was not found.

(Note: I would love to exclusively use LibreOffice but unfortunately it's the usual story: I have to collaboratively work on documents with complex tables and figures shared with Microsoft Office users, despite being able to save in the same file formats these figures are invariably interpreted differently by the various office applications.)

Answer (score 18):

In order to activate Office with a KMS you will have to edit a number of registry values. So first start the Wine registry editor for your office prefix:

1. Open PlayOnLinux
       Choose *Configure*
2. Select *Office 2010* from list of installed applications on left
3. Click on the *Wine* Tab
4. Click *Registry Editor*

Next you will have to navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`. Add the following string values under this key:

- `KeyManagementServiceName` (insert server address)
- `KeyManagementServicePort` (insert server port, default 1688)

If you don't know the values for your server ask your Sys Admin or look them up in regedit on a windows machine that has an activated copy.

Now open and exit any office application. A new key should have been created under `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`

(You may have to refresh the registry editor with <kbd>F5</kbd> to see it,)

Under this new key now add a new binary value:

- `VLRenewalSchedule` (any value)

Start Office again and check if the activation worked by looking under *File* --> *Help*

Sources:
http://wine.1045685.n5.nabble.com/Bug-30033-New-Office-2010-Standard-Volume-activation-fails-td5520490.html
https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/forum/microsoft-office-2010?msg=128241

Comment: KeyManagementServiceName (insert server address)  which server address?

Comment: @VJRanga the key management server address of your organisation - you could find it out if you have a windows machine using the same KMS server by looking in the registry

Comment: On a machine with office activated, the keyserver can be found by ```cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14``` ```cscript ospp.vbs /dhistorykms```

Comment: It might be located also here ```[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform\somelongstring\somelongstring]```